# Error while installing magento 2.4.1 through command in ubuntu

Tags: composer, magento2.4

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.1].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.

I am keep receiving this error i don't know how to resolve it.
if anyone help pls
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading your composer version to composer 1 and try again. Magento doesn't support Composer 2.

Reference Link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html#composer

Comment: i have started from composer 1 and then it was saying your composer is outdated then i upgrade then its showing this error

Comment: I am using Composer version 1.10.10  and it is working fine for me.

Comment: thanks it worked after changes made in php soap extenstion